# is there a way to combine two or more arrays into one and form a dynamic index in php at the final results my jquery can work

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

simple snippet:

```
    $mydata = array();
    $st_count = array('st_count' => 2); //just a simple data count
    foreach($fetchall as $names)
    { 
        $mydata[] = array('name' => $names['name']);
    }
    echo json_encode(array_merge($mydata, $st_count));
```

The output:

```
   {"0":{"name":"jackson"},"1":{"name":"john"},"st_count":"2"}
```

I want the above to be like:

```
 {"0":{"name":"jackson"},"1":{"name":"john"}, "2":{"st_count":"2"}}
```

If not possible how can I fetch the first result in a Jquery on:

```
   dataType: 'JSON',
   cache: false,
   success:function(response)
   {   
       $('#names').empty();
       $('#st_count').html(response.st_count);//not working
       
       for(var i=0; i < response.length; i++)
       {   
           $('#names').append(response[i].name); //not working    
       }
    }
```

Comment: `$mydata[] = $st_count;`

Comment: @Cid this combine them as I wanted, but i need an additional notes,  when i loop on the jquery side it gives both undefined and the names data, I moved  ` $('#st_count').html(response.st_count);` outside and put it in the loop as  ` $('#st_count').html(response[i].st_count);` , they are working well but on the clientb i get both undefined and the names at `#names` I'm sorry please!

Comment: @Cid, I mean when i apply this `$mydata[] = $st_count`, at the top of foreach or inside the foreach a php combine the arrays but the loop come with both undefined and the data on the client

Answer (score 1):

```
     $fetchall = array(
          array('name' => 'Lucky'),
          array('name' => 'John')
     );
     $mydata = array();
     $st_count = array();
     $st_count[] = array('st_count' => 2); //just a simple data count
     foreach($fetchall as $names)
     { 
            $mydata[] = array('name' => $names['name']);
     }
     echo json_encode(array_merge($mydata, $st_count));
```

Output

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Lucky
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => John
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [st_count] => 2
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: I changed `for(var i=0; i < response.length; i++)` to `for(var i=1; i < response.length; i++)` , it skipped the undefined value thanks, now it works